# How rendering routes from when the nav section is in a other Component ?

Tags: reactjs, react-dom

My website is split into two component, a "Side" component that displays a nav menu and a "View" with a "Menu" component that display the a specific component depends on nav button you click on.

The problem is that the component never rendering.

My Menu Component :

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Link, BrowserRouter } from 'react-
router-dom';
import './Menu.css'

class Menu extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return (
        <div className="Menu col 12" >
            <div className="Menu-link" >
                <Router>
                    <ul class="pagination">
                        <li class="waves-effect"><a href="#!"><i class="material-icons">chevron_left</i></a></li>
                        <li class="waves-effect menu-element">
                            <Link to="/work" className="nav-title">
                                <i class="material-icons">equalizer</i>
                            </Link>
                        </li>
                        <li class="waves-effect menu-element">
                            <Link to="/work" className="nav-title">
                                <i class="material-icons">work</i>
                            </Link>
                        </li>
                        <li class="waves-effect menu-element">
                            <Link to="/education" className="nav-title">
                                <i class="material-icons">library_books</i>
                            </Link>
                        </li>
                        {/* <li class="waves-effect menu-element"><a href="/skills"><i class="material-icons">equalizer</i></a></li> */}
                        <li class="waves-effect"><a href="#!"><i class="material-icons">chevron_right</i></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </Router>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
}


 export default Menu;
```

My Side component :

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link, Switch } from 'react-
router-dom'
import './View.css'

import Work from '../Work/Work'
import Skills from '../Skills/Skills'
import Education from '../Education/Education'

class View extends React.Component{
     render(){
    return (
        <Router>
            <div>
                <Switch>
                    <Route path='/work' component={Work} />
                    <Route path='/skills' component={Skills} />
                    <Route path='/education' component={Education} />
                </Switch>
            </div>
        </Router>
    )
}
}

export default View;
```

Do you have a solution to solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

So `<Route/>` and <`Link/>` components need to be children of the same `<Router/>` component. Move your `<Router/>` component up into a common ancestor of the both the view and sidebar components and remove the `<Router />` component from both the view and sidebar components.

If you're using redux you will need to wrap the component that has your `<Route/>` components with the `withRouter` HoC.

Edit: Here is a [example code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/5vw87j4zv4) to show you how this works. Click on the about and home links on the side to see the components change.

Comment: Thanks :) That's work, but with this solution my component will be render in the ancestor, not in my view component.

Comment: Put the `<Route/>` components in the view component, and they will render in the view component. The `<Route/>` will be rendered wherever they are located. The `<Router/>` is what needs to be in the common ancestor of the routes and links.

Comment: I have : You should not use <Route> or withRouter() outside a <Router>
I put the Route Component in the View Component, and import the View component in the App Component (where i put the router) https://gist.github.com/TonyGorez/e1650cb7e669337ee70ea5e7ea7394f9